# type structure for mac-adresses in C

Tags: c, mac-address

Is it possible to store a mac adress into a variable in c?
For example `AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA`

(i know that this is possible in hex, like `0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA`)

Maybe define this as a new type with `type def struct`?

Comment: `unsigned char[6]`? Or `uint8_[6]`?

Comment: You should've googled this before: [representation of MAC address in C code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c/r9QiiOWJsnA)

Comment: `unsigned long long` might do as well, but you'd give a 2 bytes.